# SonarQube is not able to recognize String.prototype method

Tags: javascript, sonarqube, sonarlint, sonarjs

SonarQube is complaining about following piece of JS code with error

> Remove this access to "contains" property, it doesn't exist, as a
>   built-in, on a String.

[image]
While I have created this method is another JS file as

```
  String.prototype.contains = function (str, startIndex) {
      return -1 !== this.indexOf(str, startIndex);
    };
```

The same issue exists with other methods created with prototype. How can I resolve this issue without excluding the files from rule check?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This rule assumes that no monkey patching is done in the project. If you use monkey patching massively, most probably it's better to disable the rule. Otherwise just mark issue as "won't fix" in SQ UI

Comment: I don't see any option of "Won't fix" in SQ, instead there is an option for "Resolve as fixed" which is only valid till next analysis is performed.

Comment: You don't have enough rights to make it, contact your SQ's admin